# Karate API : How to hit an endpoint url with post method which does not have request body

Tags: karate

I am getting below error when I am trying hit a endpoint url with post method which does not have a body. In postman I am able to hit endpoint url with post method without body. I tried all steps by referring the Karate API docs.

```
 **Error** : com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: TestScenarios.feature:56 - 
request  body is required for a POST, please use the 'request' keyword
```

**testurl is :**

```
 **test-api.test.com/test-com/api/check/initiate? 
lang=en&cntCode=us&id=8d1b9355**
```

Attempt 1:

```
Given url 'test-api.test.com/test-com/api/check/initiate?lang=en&cntCode=us&id=8d1b9355'
When method post
Then status 200
* print  response
```

Attempt 2:

```
Given url testurl
And param lang= en
And param cCode = us
And param id= '8d1b9355'
When method post
* print 'Response'+response
```

Attempt 3:

```
Given url testurl
And form field lang= en
And form field cCode = us
When method post
Then status 200
```

Can someone help me to understand the issue and wrong in my approach.

Comment: Yeah... at last i found the solution by my self. I should be be passing request body as empty like And request {}. Earlier I tried empty request but with () parenthesis not with {}

Comment: have answered anyway to help others in future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible options depending on your server:

```
* request {}
```

Or [as per the docs](https://github.com/intuit/karate#request):

```
* request ''
```